# Creating a precompiled Win64 DLL with Mono

Tags: mono

Does anyone know if it's possible to use Mono to create a precompiled Win64 DLL which could be loaded with LoadLibrary() into an executable on a Win64 machine which didn't have any runtime dependencies installed?

And if so, how one would go about doing that?

Comment: To be clear, it would be necessary for the Mono GC & runtime libs to be bundled into the DLL - The host executable can provide shim/thunk functionality to the OS to some extent, but all the .NET style functionality would need to come from the DLL.